# elasticsearch - how to store social network connections

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm indexing social network data on elasticsearch.

It is amazing for content and profiles, but with connections I'm getting some trouble...

**option 1)** index connections nested in profile document?

**option 2)** each connection is an independent document in a separated index?

What are advantages for each option?

What I will need:

- Update connections list comparing to check who is new
- Update connections list comparing to check who stopped following

Answer (score 1):

There are three options when modeling relations. The most basic one is inner objects. Everything in one document. Problem is that you cannot query the inner objects on multiple properties. You will have a match if one property of inner object a matches and another of object b. this can be overcome using nested objects. Disadvantage of nested objects is when doing a lot of them and changing them often. Everything is stored in one document. Adding a nested object means updating the complete document. This problem can be overcome using parent child relationships. These are separate documents, so cheaper to add or remove children. Disadvantage is that you cannot obtain the parents and it's children in one query.

Hope it helps.